# How to prevent "Mysql2::Error: This connection is in use by" with Sidekiq

Tags: mysql, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, database-connection, sidekiq

After running Sidekiq for a couple of hours, I see a bunch of jobs fail with `Mysql2::Error: This connection is in use by: #<Celluloid::Thread:0x0000000d1b56e0 sleep>`. Seems the Sidekiq threads are somehow conflicting over the MySQL connection pool.

`concurrency` is set to the default 25 in sidekiq.yml and the pool is 28 in database.yml. There are no long-lived queries and the exceptions happen in standard finder calls, nothing fancy.

How can I prevent this error to ensure jobs run smoothly?

Comment: what server are you using? unicorn? this is happening on development or production?

Comment: It's an independent Sidekiq processor server. Yes, production.

Comment: are you using this DB only for this workers? because if you are using the same DB for another process you'll need to see how many connections your DB is getting

Comment: No, it's used by the Rails app server too (which works fine), but I'm assuming the error is talking about another thread within the Sidekiq process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed this by isolating all the workers. It came down to Typhoeus library apparently not being thread-safe. Replaced with Net/HTTP and it works again.

Some more details at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1400#issuecomment-45838886

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused because sidekiq is getting all connections to your DB and at the same time the rails app is also requesting the connections.

You have 25 sidekiq workers but how much rails servers do you have?

e.g. if you have unicorn running 4 child workers you'll need 29 slots (at least)

Comment: The database.yml pool variable reflects connections per process, so each Unicorn also has 28 connections here. (Actually they only need 1, but it's not a problem in practice as they don't use more and don't live long.) Since Unicorns aren't having any DB problem, it's not because of contention with them. (They're also on a different machine.)

Comment: but they share the same DB, it doesn't matter about in which machine they are, and the pool is not per process is per DB

Comment: Say I have 4 Unicorns. That means there's actually (max) 125 connections. Not 28.

Comment: 4 unicorns + 25 sidekiq = 29 slots for you DB pool, they are slots for your DB, not for each process

Comment: The pool variable means how many connections per process, and there are 5 processes here, so that's 125 possible connections. (The 28 is arbitrary, it could have been 25, but I've left some excess just in case of race conditions and there's some hints at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/503 that it should be about 1.5x the # of processors even though it should theoretically be identical.)

Comment: did some research, how much connections your DB can make? if the DB is set to accept less connections that you make then you'll have some problems

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we had a lot of these errors in a specific worker type. We identified that we were using Timeout.timeout() calls in one of the jobs running in these workers. We removed those calls and these errors went away after that. For some reference as to why Timeout.timeout() calls are dangerous, please look [here](https://coderwall.com/p/1novga/ruby-timeouts-are-dangerous) and [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/862).